# What is a good way to serialize/deserialize lists of structs to/from binary?

Tags: c#, list, serialization, struct

I'm developing a heatmap tool for counter-strike.
I use[serializable] structs which describe in-game events looking like this:

```
[Serializable]
public struct KillEvent
{
    public float killerPosX;
    public float killerPosY;
    public float victimPosX;
    public float victimPosY;
    public string killerSide;
    public string victimSide;
    public string weaponType;
}
```

This one describes a kill event in-game.

Each match there are ~ 200 kills (and other stuff that I'm not going to mention) which I put into a list, which looks like this:

```
List<KillEvent> listOfKills
```

I'm having 12 similar lists, which I would like to write to a binary file, as to archive the specific counter-strike match for later use.

I then want to deserialize the binary file and retreive the lists.

I'm new to C# and programming altogether.
I'm shooting above my level with this, as I haven't given myself enough time to properly learn how to do it. For two days I've been bashing my head to try and make it happen, but I'm being mired in errors of all sorts, and I think my approach is wrong altogether.

Question:
What would be a sensible approach to what I've described above?
Any input is appreciated, but code or pseudo-code is even better due to my lack of experience.

Thank you!

Comment: JSON will do you good: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json plenty of code samples there.

Comment: Why must the data be saved as binary data? Is JSON not enough? see @trailmax link

Comment: I have no idea why it should be binary to be honest, I've only learned about serialization 2 days ago and binary serialization was my point of entry. I'll look into the link provided, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using binary serialization instead of a database to store data that should be in a database is a bad idea, also binary serialization is slow.

Therefore you really need to store this sort of data in a database; since you're new to C# I figured that I should spend a few minutes putting together a [small sample Entity Framework database using local DB](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvbsHHF00E7F8hknpJ0G54T7W91o?e=15MbxL) that demonstrates it. Tested with VS2013 and VS2015 to show how easily this can be done.

To add to an existing project, the following should work.

1. Ensure you're referencing EntityFramework (package.config)

   ```
    <packages>
        <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
    </packages>
   ```
2. add a class derived from DbContext that is the interface to the data store

   ```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    public class Data : DbContext
    {
        // Your context has been configured to use a 'Data' connection string from your application's
        // configuration file (App.config or Web.config). By default, this connection string targets the
        // 'db_demo.Data' database on your LocalDb instance.
        //
        // If you wish to target a different database and/or database provider, modify the 'Data'
        // connection string in the application configuration file.
        public Data()
            : base("name=Data")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<KillEvent> KillEvents { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class KillEvent
    {
        [Key]
        public int KillEventId { get; set; }

        public float killerPosX { get; set; }
        public float killerPosY { get; set; }
        public float victimPosX { get; set; }
        public float victimPosY { get; set; }
        public string killerSide { get; set; }
        public string victimSide { get; set; }
        public string weaponType { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Id{0,6}: Side {1}, weapon {2}, pos ({3},{4}) victim  side {5} pos ({6},{7}) ",
                KillEventId,
                killerSide,
                weaponType,
                killerPosX,
                killerPosY,
                victimSide,
                victimPosX, victimPosY
                );
        }
    }
   ```
3. Test method to create test data

   ```
    var db = new Data();
    var rng = new Random();
    if (!db.KillEvents.Any())
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Populating with test data");
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var data = new KillEvent()
            {
                killerPosX = rng.Next(0, 1000),
                killerPosY = rng.Next(0, 1000),
                killerSide = rng.Next(0, 3).ToString(),
                victimPosX = rng.Next(0, 1000),
                victimPosY = rng.Next(0, 1000),
                victimSide = rng.Next(0, 3).ToString(),
                weaponType = "AIM-" + (9 + Math.Round((int)rng.Next(0, 2) * 111.0)).ToString(),
            };
            db.KillEvents.Add(data);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
   ```
4. Method to dump data

   ```
    var db1 = new Data();
    foreach (var ke in db1.KillEvents)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Ke {0}", ke.ToString());
    }
   ```
5. Method to extract data with LINQ

   ```
    var db1 = new Data();
    foreach (var groupedBySide in db1.KillEvents.GroupBy(xx=>xx.killerSide))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Side {0} has {1} kills ", groupedBySide.Key, groupedBySide.Count());
    }
   ```

Comment: I know comments are supposed to be about further questions and corrections, but I really want to thank you for the time you've spent trying to help me. What an elaborate and clear explanation!
I found a way to make it work through JSON, but I will study the database approach as well, since I'll need this knowledge in the not too distant future.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you can serialize it to Json as Comments Mentioned
but if you really need to Serialize It To Binary File You can use Binaryformatter 
this Is Example how to Use

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

    void Serialize(string path, KillEvent ev)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileShare.None);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(fs, ev);
    }
```

and check more 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input! I'll research Json and see if I can get stuff working.